# Unable to insert a record in db in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am new user in php. I am trying insert in a table using following query:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO forget (key,user_name) values('Abc','Xyz')";
mysql_query($insert)
echo mysql_error();
```

Output:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key,user_name) values('abc','xyz')' at line 1

Comment: please edit your question so that it is readable, with code-blocks, etc...

Comment: learn to interpret error messages. MySQL was telling you `for the right syntax to use near 'key` - **near `'key`**. Plus, don't bother using the plural form, `keys` is a reserved word also. Stay away from using those as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a few reserved words which will cause queries using them to fail.  In this case it is `key`.

You can either change the column name (also known as "key" which is why it fails) or you can escape the term with backticks like so:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO forget (`key`,user_name) values('Abc','Xyz')";
```

Comment: 1.  Are you sure you are using backticks and not single quotes?   2.  If so, can you provide your table structure?  There's something missing from the information you provided

Comment: I have change the column name. Structure is index,recover,username int,varchar,varchar

Answer (score 0):

Here are the list of words what mysql has reserved, and that cant be used as a table or field name in a query, unless its escaped using back ticks. You can use them as your field name, but when you query it, it must be escaped using " ` ".

In your case, `key` is a reserved word. So you must either escape it using back ticks.

Here is a list of mysql reserved words : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html